# Convert List of Points to a Bounding Box in Matlab

Tags: matlab, transform, points, bounding-box

I have a bounding box:

```
 bbox = [10 20 50 60];
```

I convert the bounding box to a list of points using:

```
 points = bbox2points(bbox);
```

I then apply a rotation to the points using *affine2d* and *transformPointsForward*. Now I have my transformed points, how can I convert them back to a bounding box? Is there some built in function equivalent to "points2bbox"? Thanks.

Comment: In general, you can't. The original bounding box was axis aligned. Your transformed points may not be. In which case they cannot be described by x,y,w,h; you also need the angle of rotation. The answer to this question will depend on whether you know there is a rotation or not.

Comment: The angle of rotation is known in all cases. The question can also be posed another way: I have an image, a small part of which is surrounded by a bounding box. I rotate the image x degrees. How can I also rotate the bounding box by the *same* angle, thus keeping the bounding box in registration? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the transformation in fact affine? Shear won't leave you with a rectangle. If it's just translation and rotation (rigid), don't bother converting to points and applying the transform. Just add the translation component to the (x,y) of your bounding box, and record the angle of rotation. You now have an (x,y,w,h,theta) representation of the bounding box.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use a bbox with a theta component. I need the bbox in the format [x y w h]. For a rigid rotation, how to I calculate the new bbox coordinates? For example, bbox = [10 20 50 60]; in plane rotation of +90 degrees? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now sorted. I just flipped the images in various ways and then calculated the new bounding box position using the angle of rotation and the dimensions of the original image (which remained constant).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make a bbox from points without worrying about a transformation, do this. I just made this, and it works.

```
function bbox = points2bbox(roi)
% This is a function that takes in an roi (a set of four points) and
% outpouts a bbox (which is in for form of x,y,w,h, where x and y
% correspond to the lower left of the coordinates for the points. 

% MAKE SURE THAT YOUR POINTS MAKE A RECTANGLE! 
% THIS IS WHAT BBOX HERE DESCRIBES!

% Getting x and y data
x = roi(:,1);
y = roi(:,2);

% Getting width and height
width = max(x) - min(x);
height = max(y) - min(y);

% Constructing bbox
bbox = [min(x) min(y) width height]
end
```

Where the roi (Region of Interest in my research) is a set of points with the first column as the x coordinates and the second column as the y coordinates.